# Search Icon Distorted in iPhone 6 Plus - Squashed to an Egg Shape

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have a search bar in the navigation title view. And two buttons as the right bar button items. After rotating the device a number of times, the shape of the search icon seems to be squashed and becomes a egg-like shape.  See the following image.

[image]

Here is a minimum implementation that I can find to reproduce this:

- Create new project from template **Single View Application**
- Go to the main storyboard and embed in a navigation controller (Editor > Embed In> Navigation Controller)
- Replace the following code in `ViewController.m`:

  ```
  @interface ViewController ()
  @property (nonatomic, strong) UISearchBar *searchBar;
  @property (nonatomic, strong) UIBarButtonItem* addButton;
  @property (nonatomic, strong) UIBarButtonItem* editButton;
  @end

  @implementation ViewController
  - (void)viewDidLoad {
      [super viewDidLoad];
      // Add a search bar
      _searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] init];
      _searchBar.placeholder = @"Search";
      self.navigationItem.titleView = _searchBar;
      // Add two buttons
      _addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:nil];
      _editButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Edit" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
      self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = @[_editButton, _addButton];
  }
  @end
  ```
- Compile and run it either in iPhone 6+ simulator, or iPhone 6+ device. Rotate the device a number of times and you will the search icon is distorted gradually.

Additional notes:

- This seems to happens only on iPhone 6 Plus. We tested on a lot of other devices (including but not limited to iPhone 6, iPhone 5s) and don't this issue.
- If we replace the placeholder for `UISearchBar` with some other string (other than "Search"), we don't see the distortion.

Comment: You should file this as a bug report with Apple.

Comment: I am have this issue too, did you resolve it?

Comment: Hello @BeWarned. Yes, I work around this issue by removing the placeholder text from the search bar. And it has been alright ever since then. However, the bug is still open for Apple. I will update the post when it is fixed by Apple.

Comment: We set and changed the placeholder text based on the context, but still see this issue.

Comment: @BeWarned, I would recommend you file a bug report as well. The more people bring up this issue to Apple, the more likely that they will fix it. It seems that your bug may not be exactly the same as mine. Another thing that you can try is see how it works in iOS 9. They might have fixed it in the new release even though I doubt it very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have submitted bug report to Apple for this one and will keep you guys updated.

The bug seems to be related to the size of the buttons **and** the size of placeholder string. Some work around that for us so far:

- Replace the placeholder string to something else other than "Search":
- Use some other buttons either such as by changing the title "Edit" to something else.

Answer (score 2):

We have exactly the same issue with a distorted UISearchBar Icon - only happening on iPhone 6/7 Plus.

For now we only found a crazy workaround with method swizzling and resetting the frame of the icon in layoutSubviews of UISearchBar.

Any better workaround is welcome :-)

```
import UIKit

private var defaultImageViewSize: CGSize? = nil

private let swizzling: (UISearchBar.Type) -> () = { searchBar in
    let originalSelector = #selector(searchBar.layoutSubviews)
    let swizzledSelector = #selector(searchBar.proj_layoutSubviews)

    let originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(searchBar, originalSelector)
    let swizzledMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(searchBar, swizzledSelector)

    method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod)
}

extension UISearchBar {

    open override class func initialize() {
        // make sure this isn't a subclass
        guard self === UISearchBar.self else { return }
        swizzling(self)
    }

    // MARK: - Method Swizzling
    func proj_layoutSubviews(animated: Bool) {
        self.proj_layoutSubviews(animated: animated)

        if let imageView = self.getSearchBarIcon(inView: self) {
            if let defaultImageViewSize = defaultImageViewSize {
                imageView.frame.size = defaultImageViewSize
            } else {
                defaultImageViewSize = imageView.frame.size
            }
        }
    }

    private func getSearchBarIcon(inView view: UIView) -> UIImageView? {
        for subview in view.subviews {
            if subview.isMember(of: UIImageView.self), let imageView = subview as? UIImageView {
                return imageView
            } else if let imageView = getSearchBarIcon(inView: subview) {
                return imageView
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```